# PHP Regex to find a specific substring

Tags: php, regex, substring

So basically, I have a big string with some other information, and somewhere at the end, I have the following structure of a string:

```
62AC979D-5277D720
```

It is numbers and uppercase letters. I would like to extract this substring from many lines of the bigger strings which all contain it at different places. I have tried:

```
preg_match('/^[\w]+$/', $string);
```

But I really don't have much experience with regular expressions. Can someone provide the regex necessary or at least tell me where I am mistaken? Thank you for your time!

Comment: simple, `preg_match('/^[\w-]+$/', $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do it for you,

```
([A-Z\d]{8}-[A-Z\d]{8})
```

in use

```
<?php
$string = 'This is 62AC979D-5277D720 the whole string.';
preg_match_all('~([A-Z\d]{8}-[A-Z\d]{8})~', $string, $value);
print_r($value[1]);
```

Your current regex fails I suspect because of the `^` and `$`. These mark the start and end of the string you are searching for (or line if the `m` modifier is used). The `\w` is also `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`. I think you only care about capital letters and you want to allow only one dash. If the target will also always only be 8 characters you can add the `{8}` in place of the `+`. The `()` are to capture the value that is found. The first found value in `$string` will be `$value[1][0]`.

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6b2c391d95c5454a3c7ea81d5ac4a3bb8e49aef

Comment: This is the one, but how can I limit the characters before and after the "-" to be 8, because there are dates in the string like 2015-12 so they match that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\\b[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+\\b/')
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\\b[0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{8}\\b/', $string);
```

This works for the string you gave i.e 8 numbers or alphabets followed by - and then numbers and alphabets again

Answer (score 0):

You try this.

```
 preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{8}$/', $string)
```